# How to extract particular xml part from the given xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need extract `<C></C>`, by passing a parameter to the xslt like below

```
<C>
<D></D>
<D></D>
</C>
```

from the below XML using xslt.

```
<A>
<B/>
<C>
<D></D>
<D></D>
</C>
<E><D></D></E>
</A>
```

If I able to set the value for the element as "C", how I able to perform the above operation. My current xslt template like below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:param name="element" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <$element>
         <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(//D)" />
         </xsl:processing-instruction>
         <xsl:copy-of select="/A/$element/D" />
      </$element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thx a lot Potame its worked for me. Could you tell me is this possible? <xsl:if test="$element = 'C'">$element ="E"</xsl:if> to get effected <E></E> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to enter an element name as a parameter and use it directly in the XPath for the `select`s.

However you could refactor your stylesheet this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:param name="element" select="'C'"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="{$element}">

         <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(//D)" />
         </xsl:processing-instruction>

         <xsl:copy-of select="/A/*[name() = $element]/D" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result obtained :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C>
  <?xml-multiple D?>
  <D/><D/>
</C>
```

corresponds to the desired output.